# How to test a public async function inside Class using Jest in a ReactJS/Typescript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, jestjs

> Property 'getUsersTotalPayout` does not exist on type typeof PayoutApi

**My Class:**

```
import { bind } from 'decko';

import BaseApi from './Base';
import * as NS from './types';

class PayoutApi extends BaseApi {

  @bind
  public async getUsersTotalPayout(userId: string): Promise<number> {
    const params: NS.IGetUsersTotalPayoutRequest = { userId };
    const response = await this.actions.get<{ payout: number }>(
      '/api/get-total-payout',
      params,
    );
    return response.data.payout;
  }
}

export default PayoutApi;
```

**The test file:**

```
import PayoutApi from './LiquidityPool';

const endpoint = '/api/get-total-payout';

const userId = 'foo';

jest.mock(endpoint, () => ({
  getUsersTotalPayout: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { payout: 100.21 } }))
}));

describe('API: getUsersTotalPayout', () => {
  it('should make a request when we get images', () => {
    // const testApi = new PayoutApi();
    expect(PayoutApi.getUsersTotalPayout(userId)).toHaveBeenCalledWith(endpoint, 'GET');
  });
});
```

Getting that error on `expect(PayoutApi.getUsersTotalPayout).toHaveBeenCalledWith(endpoint, 'GET');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are currently trying to call method on the class. Since it is not `static` you should instantiate object of class first.

   ```
   let api = new PayoutApi();
   expect(api.getUsersTotalPayout(userId).....)
   ```
2. since `jest.mock` mocks module not endpoint or XHR request your test will try sending live request to /api/get-total-payout. For handling that it's needed to know what XHR wrapper do you use. Say for `fetch()` there is [nice wrapper-mocker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock) and libraries like axios also have their equivalence.
3. As for test itself. It does not work if you call a method and make `expect` on its result. It should be running method that must call server and then checking for mocked XHR if it has been called with valid parameters:

   ```
   api.getUsersTotalPayout(userId);
   expect(fetch_or_other_wrapper_for_mocking_xhr.get_last_request_method()).toEqual('get', endpoint, userId)
   ```